# Prevent Raspberry Pi 3 from automatically connecting to bluetooth le device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, raspberry-pi3

I have a TI SensorTag bluetooth le device.  It is not paired with my raspberry Pi.  I installed bluez, but I don't have any applications of my own running.  The second I power on the device, something on the Pi instantly connects to it.  If I disable bluetooth on the Pi, the device becomes available for connections.

This is a problem for me because my own application can't connect to the device because something on the Pi has aggressively connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the reason is but this worked for me. Try following steps.

1. Go to terminal and type `bluetoothctl`.
2. Then type `disconnect <device_address>`